# Vim: Visual mode from the end of a line

Tags: vim

I am new to using Vim.

In other text editors, I can go to the end of a line and start highlighting characters on that line **including the last character on the line**.

In vim, is there a way to select characters from the end of the line in visual mode? When I go to the end of a line and start selecting text from the end, I cannot include the last character in the line.

[image]

Here, I moved my cursor to the end of the line, but cannot select the 'e' in example in visual mode. Does anybody know how to get around this?

Comment: Did you try to copy&paste selection? It might be just the way your terminal displays it (I think ConEmu does something like this). So my guess is that you see last character not selected, but it is actually selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting selection mode:

```
set sel=inclusive
```

> "inclusive" means that the last character of the selection is included
>       in an operation.

Answer (score 1):

You have `:set selection=exclusive`; with that, it's indeed difficult to create a selection from back to front. Here are some ways:

- the already mentioned `:set selection=inclusive`, but this changes the entire selection semantics
- `:set virtualedit=onemore`; then go beyond the last character with `$l` and start the selection there
- by including the last character with `$`, and only then extending to the front: `v$ob`
- of course, the easiest way is to start the selection from the *front*, and then include the last character via the `$` motion.

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely select the last character of a line.
To be sure that the cursor is really at the end of the line, you can use the `$` movement.